# Can these functions that call functions be combined in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on a game, and I've created a function in my `Player()` class that calls another function for every other player in the game (in order). However, I can't figure out if it's possible to generalize it for the various different functions I'm using in the game, which each have different numbers of arguments.

I've turned it into two functions, but will need to extend this at least as far as `every_other_player3`:

```
def every_other_player0(self, func): 
    i = self.self_index()
    j = i + 1
    while j % len(players) != i:
        func(players[j % len(players)])
        j += 1

def every_other_player1(self, func, arg1=None): 
    i = self.self_index()
    j = i + 1
    while j % len(players) != i:
        func(players[j % len(players)], arg1)
        j += 1
```

Here's examples of how I'm calling these:

```
player.every_other_player0(Player.draw_card) # Players draw from their deck
player.every_other_player1(Player.get_card, 'Spade') # Players get a Spade from a group pile
```

`players` is just a list of `Player` objects, which I'm using for the turn order.

Is there a way to unify these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use a packed argument list:

```
def every_other_player(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
    i = self.self_index()
    j = i + 1
    while j % len(players) != i:
        func(players[j % len(players)], *args, **kwargs)
        j += 1
```

Note that the `Player` methods you plan on passing to `every_other_player()` via the `func` parameter (e.g. `draw_card()` and `get_card()`) can remain unchanged and are blissfully ignorant that you are packing/unpacking arguments.

See, for example, this [reference](http://hangar.runway7.net/python/packing-unpacking-arguments).

Comment: It took some research and trial and error to figure out that the `*args` and `**kwargs` don't have to show up anywhere at all except in `every_other_player()`. I thought I had to come up with a way to reference them in the functions that would call `every_other_player()`. My example calls are now exactly the same except for standardizing the function name.

Comment: Sorry for not making that clear.  I updated my answer with a statement to that effect.